# SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="Un known property 'replication_factor'">

Tags: cassandra

I am having error in cassandra while executing following query.

> create keyspace testkeyspace with replication_factor=3;
>
> SyntaxException: < ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="Un known property 'replication_factor'">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual for [`CREATE KEYSPACE`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/create_keyspace_r.html) shows how to use this correctly.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE Excelsior WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
```

Comment: Thank you, I did CREATE KEYSPACE Excelsior
  WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 }; and it worked